# webpack require library that is not a npm module

Tags: jquery, npm, webpack

i am trying to require a library that is not a module.

I have required jquery as a module and put it into the variable $.
But the lirbary jqwidgets is not a npm module and it depends on jquery.

So i tried to require it. but i do get the message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘jqx’ of undefined
```

Is there any way to get the none module libraries to work when they need a global variable like jquery uses $ or jQuery?

Comment: Would be interested to know if you ever find a solution to your problem. We face the same problem even though jqWidgets can now be installed using npm

Comment: At the time i was working on this issue there did exist a npm module for jqwidgets. But it didnt work, i found the issue and reported it to jqwidgets on their forum. It was missing a main in the package.json and it did not have a module.exports in the files.  They have fixed it now. but they included the jqxall into the main. i didnt want to include everything so i decided to change the package.json tho. even with the complexity of having to remeber to change that if i get a fresh copy of the code again. to run npm install.